# ELB Balancing Stateful Servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Let's say i have this HTTP2 service, that has a list of users and this user hair color, in memory and database well.

Now i want to scale this up into multiple nodes - however i do not want the same user to be in two different servers memory - each server shall handle those specific users. This means i need to inform the load balancer where each user is being handled. In case of de-scaling, i need to inform this user is nowhere and can be routed to any server or by a given rule - IE server with less memory being used.

Would any1 know if ALB load balancer supports that ? One path i was thinking of using Query string parameter-based routing, so i could inform in the request itself something like `destination_node = (int)user_id % 4` in case i had 4 nodes for instance - and this worked well in a proof of concept but that leads to a few issues:

- The service itself would need to know how many instances there are to balance.
- I could not guarantee even balancing, its basically a luck based balancing.

What would be the preferred approach for this, or what is a common way of solving this problem ? Does AWS ELB supports this out of the box ? I was trying to avoid having to write my own balancer, a middleware that keeps track of what services are handling what users, whose responsibility would be distributing the requests among those servers.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) it is possible to write Routing-Rules on

- Host Header
- HTTP Header
- HTTP Request Method
- Path Pattern
- Query String
- Source IP

But at the moment there is no way to route under dynamic conditions. 
If it possible to group your data, i would prefere path pattern like 
`/users/blond/123`

Comment: In case i balance using Path Pattern like u said - does this means for one of the given path parameters, always the same server will be used ?

Comment: One Path match can routed to a Target Group (1-n servers) or to an http endpoint.